# How to get the "GET" url from a website with a SUBMIT button?

Tags: php, forms, jsp, button, submit

I have this site https://teleservices. paris .fr/fourrieres/ (remove the blank in the URL) and I would like to recreate the form submit using a GET url method.

I looked at the source code :

```
<button type="submit" class="button" name="action_rechercher">
CONTINUER <img class="arrow-bottom" src="images/arrow-bottom.png">
</button>
```

but I don't understand the code. I would like to be able to use a URL like, so I can call the result directly from a link like this one

https://teleservices. paris .fr/fourrieres/action?immatriculation=TY32EYU

Hope you understand, 
Thanks for your help

Comment: No, I don’t understand. What is your actual question here? How forms basically work?

Answer (score 2):

```
<form name="yourFormName" method="GET" action="someFile">
  <!-- Do something -->
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add some more context around your answer?

Comment: I like do make my own page to propose my own form using this site : https://teleservices.paris.fr/fourrieres/

But How do I create a new page getting the form answer. Thanks